# Problem using Access control lists for new users, ex ( afolder created in skel directoy have acl set, it should apply to new users)

Tags: acl, defaults, user-default

I have a doubt regarding ACL

I want to give permissions to a group using ACL

A directory created in SKEL directory needs to have a default ACL set that allows the
members of the group “linux” to read all files and subdirectories.

But after doing above steps, if i add new user to a system with group as linux it
is not applying default ACL.Need some help

Comment: If you copy a directory with default ACLs with `cp -a` does the duplicate have the default ACLs, too?

Comment: i can do that but if you add a folder in skel directory and set defaults acl for the directory
When you create a new users contents of skel directory are copied to users home directory but ACL are not set

Comment: My `useradd` (openSUSE 13.2) does copy the default ACLs. You may file a bug report.